# PHP exec() not working even with simpliest example from php.net

Tags: php, exec

I can't run even simple function like: `echo exec('whoami');`.

Safe mode is `off`, webservice is IIS. Could someone please suggest something?

Comment: Enable error reporting?

Comment: Pretty sure `whoami` is a shell command (in Windows), not an executable. Try using a shell instead (`shell_exec` instead of `exec`), or try to execute an actual executable.

Comment: @KristerAndersson sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` to the top of your script.

Comment: @Machavity no, it is not disabled. I guess. At least not in php.ini

Comment: @netcoder Tried shell_exec too, but the same nothing.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to print it out right away or store it in a variable, for example:

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$whoami = exec('whoami');
echo $whoami;
?>
```

OR to get the results as an array

```
<?php
exec('whoami', $result);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

returns something like:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "pc0004\whatever" }
```

Comment: I think that is not the problem.. Tried your's little script, but nope - didn't work.

Comment: Hmm.. Now it returned "array(0) { }"  It's something, but still not what expected..

Comment: Then you have some real issues with your configuration.^^ All those solutions work in their way for me.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I have some REAL issues :D Anyways - thanks for time :)